# Use jTextField text in one JFrame in a seperate JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, jtextfield

Two hours of google searches and I now do admit defeat. I am working on a simple java program but I just can't figure out how to get the text from one jTextField to equal the text of another jTextField in a separate jFrame. The variables in question are accNumber in NewJFrame.java and AccnDynamicLabel in NewFrame.java. I am looking to make the text within AccDynamicLabel equal to the text in accNumber when the user clicks the createBtn in NewJFrame.java. Here is my code for the two java files

NewJFrame.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package bank;

/**
 *
 * @author CJ
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        accnLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        accBal = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        createBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        accNumber = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        accBalText = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        accnLabel.setText("Account Number");

        accBal.setText("Initial Balance");

        createBtn.setText("Create");
        createBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                createBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        accNumber.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                accNumberInputMethodTextChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        accBalText.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                accBalTextInputMethodTextChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
        panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(accnLabel)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(accNumber)
                .addGap(10, 10, 10))
            .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(accBal)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(createBtn)
                        .addGap(0, 73, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(accBalText))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(accnLabel)
                    .addComponent(accNumber, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addGroup(panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(accBal)
                    .addComponent(accBalText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(createBtn)
                .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void createBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        NewFrame f = new NewFrame();
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }                                         

    private void accNumberInputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String x = accNumber.getText();
    }                                                

    private void accBalTextInputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String y = accBal.getText();
    }                                                 

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel accBal;
    public javax.swing.JTextField accBalText;
    public javax.swing.JTextField accNumber;
    private javax.swing.JLabel accnLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton createBtn;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

NewFrame.java:

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    package bank;

    /**
     *
     * @author CJ
     */
    public class NewFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        /**
         * Creates new form NewFrame
         */
        public NewFrame() {
            initComponents();
        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            depLab = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            withLab = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            deposit = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            withdraw = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            submit = new javax.swing.JButton();
            accnLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            AccnDynamicLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            BalanceStaticLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            BalanceDynamicLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 200));

            depLab.setText("Deposit");

            withLab.setText("Withdraw");

            submit.setText("Submit");

            accnLabel.setText("Account Number:");

            AccnDynamicLabel.setText("N/A");

            BalanceStaticLabel.setText("Balance:");

            BalanceDynamicLabel.setText("N/A");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(depLab)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(deposit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(withLab)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(submit)
                                .addComponent(withdraw, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(accnLabel))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                            .addComponent(AccnDynamicLabel))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                    .addComponent(BalanceDynamicLabel))
                                .addComponent(BalanceStaticLabel))))
                    .addContainerGap(45, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(depLab)
                                .addComponent(deposit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(accnLabel))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(withLab)
                                .addComponent(withdraw, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                            .addComponent(AccnDynamicLabel)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(BalanceStaticLabel)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(BalanceDynamicLabel)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(submit)
                    .addGap(23, 23, 23))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new NewFrame().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JLabel AccnDynamicLabel;
        private javax.swing.JLabel BalanceDynamicLabel;
        private javax.swing.JLabel BalanceStaticLabel;
        private javax.swing.JLabel accnLabel;
        private javax.swing.JLabel depLab;
        private javax.swing.JTextField deposit;
        private javax.swing.JButton submit;
        private javax.swing.JLabel withLab;
        private javax.swing.JTextField withdraw;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `accNumber and AccnDynamicLabel` - first of all start by using standard Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Be consistent!!!

Comment: Alright, I changed the variable names to proper lower case first, what would be a good way for me to now parse the text across the jFrames

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580000/transfer-data-from-one-jframe-to-another-jframe-using-static-class-or-this-refer

Comment: Keep your text in a [GUI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) that both JFrames read from and your GUI controller updates.